# Grouped Series in Apache Echarts

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts

I am using the JavaScript plot library `Echats`, and I reached into the following issue. I want to represent some values and their regression together. That means that when I click the respective legend, both time series are shown. I got that by using the `markLine` Echarts component. Currently, it leads to the picture plot:
[image]

Nevertheless, due to [this open incident](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/14835#issuecomment-903303711), when you zoom the data, the regression line disappears. As a workaround, I was thinking about just creating 2 regular series, but for the moment, I did not get any way to show both of them when you click the legend (I don´t want the regression to be in the legend, but just show up respectively for each of the values there).

Is there anyway to use a sort of nested series structure? Any other potential solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, there is no way to do that in Echarts.

Using React, I used a workaround by creating a state and saving there the selected legend. By passing this parameter to the Echart component, you can play with which time series will be shown.